# return a list of objects in c#

Tags: c#, list, function

i need to build a list in a function, then return it to a another list variable
the problem is: inside the function the list is built properly but when i return it to the outer variable it seems like all the elements of the outer list are all similar to the last one added to it inside the function. what is the reason of this?

this is my code:

```
List<stu> fillObject(SqlDataReader rd)
    {
        List<stu> stList = new List<stu>();
        stu stObj = new stu();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            stObj.username = rd["username"].ToString();
            stObj.password = rd["password"].ToString();
            stObj.fname = rd["fname"].ToString();
            stObj.lname = rd["lname"].ToString();
            stObj.faculty = rd["faculty"].ToString();
            stList.Add(stObj);

        }
        return stList;
    }
```

here is the call of the function:

```
var friendsList = fillObject(rd);
```

so looping though 'friendList' would give the same last object added in the builder function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
List<stu> fillObject(SqlDataReader rd)
    {
        List<stu> stList = new List<stu>();

        while (rd.Read())
        {
            stu stObj = new stu();
            stObj.username = rd["username"].ToString();
            stObj.password = rd["password"].ToString();
            stObj.fname = rd["fname"].ToString();
            stObj.lname = rd["lname"].ToString();
            stObj.faculty = rd["faculty"].ToString();
            stList.Add(stObj);

        }
        return stList;
    }
```

what you were missing is initializing `stu` inside `while`, due to which there was only one `stu` object that is being added again and again into `stList`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create New STU object inside the loop, Otherwise you keep changing the same referenced object.

Comment: i need x-y, but i don't know who is bigger
is there a max(x,y)-min(x,y) in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
List<stu> fillObject(SqlDataReader rd)
{
    List<stu> stList = new List<stu>();
    //stu stObj = new stu();
    while (rd.Read())
    {

       stList.Add(new stu 
       {
        username = rd["username"].ToString(),
        password = rd["password"].ToString(),
        fname = rd["fname"].ToString(),
        lname = rd["lname"].ToString(),
        faculty = rd["faculty"].ToString()

      });

    }
    return stList;
}
```

Comment: do you really mean: stObj.Add() ?

Comment: there is no need to create stu class object inside loop.